# Error in .bst file "---the literal stack isn't empty for entry..."

Tags: natbib, bibliographystyle, bst

So, I am modifying an existing .bst to have some specific Harvard-style references and so far everything seems to work except for my **@incollection function** (here below), for which I receive the "empty literal stack" message. I am using the [authoryear] **natbib package**.

```
FUNCTION {incollection}
{ output.bibitem
  format.authors "author" output.check
  author format.key output
  format.date "year" output.check
  date.bracket
  format.title "title" output.check
  new.sentence
  crossref missing$
    { format.in.ed.booktitle "booktitle" output.check
      format.edition output
      new.sentence
      format.bvolume output
      format.number.series output
      new.sentence
      format.publisher.address output
      format.chapter.pages output
    }
    { format.incoll.inproc.crossref output.nonnull
      format.chapter.pages output
    }
  if$
  format.pages "pages" output.check
  fin.entry
}
```

I tried to identify the source of the error and it seems that has something to do with my "**format.publisher.address**" or "**format.org.or.pub**" function (not sure which of the two), which I pasted here below. Yet, I was not able to identify which specific bit of the code gives the error.

```
FUNCTION {format.org.or.pub}
{ 't :=
  ""
  address empty$ t empty$ and
    'skip$
    {
      t empty$
        { address empty$
          'skip$
          { address * }
          if$
        }
        { t *
          address empty$
            'skip$
            { ", " * address * }
          if$
        }
      if$
    }
  if$
}

FUNCTION {format.publisher.address}
{ publisher empty$
    { "empty publisher in " cite$ * warning$
      ""
    }
    {format.org.or.pub}
  if$ 
 }
```

For the sake of clarity, here is an example of the @incollection bib entry that gives the error:

```
@incollection{illeris_comprehensive_2018,
    address = {Abingdon, Oxon; New York, NY},
    edition = {2},
    title = {A comprehensive understanding of human learning},
    isbn = {978-1-138-55048-3 978-1-138-55049-0},
    abstract = {None},
    booktitle = {Contemporary theories of learning: learning theorists... in their own words},
    publisher = {Routledge},
    author = {Illeris, Knud},
    editor = {Illeris, Knud},
    year = {2018},
    keywords = {Adult learning, Learning, Philosophy},
    pages = {1--14},
}
```

Thanks in advance for your time and help!

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SE. Assuming that the bst file "worked" prior to you applying some edits, what are the changes you made?